# Automatically install most useful packages

Tags: r, install.packages

I need to install this list of packages:

I have found [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/08/list-r-packages-data-analysis/) this code:

```
list.of.packages <- c("dplyr", "plyr", "data.table", "MissForest", "MissMDA",
"Outliers", "EVIR", "Features", "RRF", "FactorMiner", "CCP",
"ggplot2", "googkleVis", "Rcharts", "car", "randomforest",
"Rminer", "CoreLearn", "caret", "BigRF", "CBA",
"RankCluster", "forecat", "LTSA", "survival", "Basta",
"LSMean", "Comparison", "RegTest", "ACD", "BinomTools",
"DAIM", "ClustEval", "SigClust", "PROC", "TimeROC", "Rcpp",
"parallel", "xml", "httr", "rjson", "jasonlite", "shiny",
"Rmarkdown", "tm", "OpenNLP", "sqldf", "RODBC", "rmonogodb")

new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages
    %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
    if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
    lapply(list.of.packages,function(x){library(x,character.only=TRUE)})
```

for which I get this response:

```
 There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary   source needs_compilation
bit     1.1-15.1 1.1-15.2              TRUE
foreach    1.4.7    1.4.8             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) lapply(list.of.packages,function(x){library(x,character.only=TRUE)})
Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “lapply(list.of.packages,function(x){library(x,character.only=TRUE)})”
```

Do you know what 'unrecognised response' means? Could you help me finding a way to install the packages in one go?

Comment: The function was expecting to receive interactive input and is interpreting the rest of the code you are running as user input to the prompt. Add `type="binary"` or `type="source"` to your `install.packages()` call so it doesn't try to ask you interactively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`install.packages` asks for user input in "There are binary versions available...", and reads the next line from the input buffer, which is “lapply(list.of.packages,function(x){library(x,character.only=TRUE)})”

Are you running R from a terminal or Rstudio? In the latter case, try running one line at a time, so that you can decide to upgrade packages or not, before all the libraries are loaded on the next line.